# SQL Syntax error in insert query

Tags: syntax-error, sql-insert

Hi to all i am getting  error in insert query
below is query

echo $sql="INSERT INTO event(mode,title,desc,date,status)VALUES('$mode','$title','$desc','$date','$status')";

and below is error

**Error in your SQL syntax**

Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`'desc,date,status)VALUES('Event','fdsagsd','fa sdgavsd ','2015-01-21','1')' at line 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desc is misunderstood*. you need to either escape it with `` or use a better name for the column like description (prefferably the later or both).

```
INSERT INTO event(mode,title,`desc`,date,status)VALUES('Event','fdsagsd','fa sdgavsd ','2015-01-21','1');
```

- Desc is also used in SELECT queries to order a result descending by a specified column.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `desc` is a reserved word (think of `order by`), so you need to quota it with backticks when you're using it as a column name.

From [section 9.2 of the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index, column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, tablespace, and other object names are known as identifiers. This section describes the permissible syntax for identifiers in MySQL. Section 9.2.2, “Identifier Case Sensitivity”, describes which types of identifiers are case sensitive and under what conditions.
>
> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it.
>
> ...
>
> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
> ```

So the SQL you want is:

```
INSERT INTO event(mode, title, `desc`, date, status)
VALUES ('Event', 'fdsagsd', 'fa sdgavsd ', '2015-01-21','1')
```

(The extra spaces aren't *necessary* of course, but I'd recommend including them just to make the SQL more readable.)

Of course, given that you'll need to quote the column name everywhere you use it, you may well decide it would be simpler to just rename it so that it's *not* a reserved word - that partly depends on how much other code already uses the schema.

Answer (score 0):

As date and desc are keys, Add Backtick (`) before and after each fields.

Comment: `date` doesn't require quoting - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html. Of course, it *can* be quoted.